# status bar icon showed for one second then disappear

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa

I'm trying some stuff, to test the status bar icon feature.

I think I got the all the functions right. However when run. The icon displayed for about 1 mili second then disappeared.

Below is the screenshot of my code:

[image: the code]

source code: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/drdxi2zgumc4c3l/s-4J1S418s

Demo video: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/8032222/the%20app%20run%20weird.mov

Comment: :-) Next time, just post the code rather than a screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Retain` statusItem object.

```
statusItem=[[[NSStatusBar systemStatusBar] statusItemWithLength:NSVariableStatusItemLength]retain];
```

From Documentation of `statusItemWithLength:`.

> The receiver does not retain a reference to the status item, so you
>   need to retain it. Otherwise, the object is removed from the status
>   bar when it is deallocated.

Comment: Note that retain will be forbidden if you are using ARC.